# Modifying the histogram curve for positive x

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have some histogram code as follows:

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)
sns.distplot(x1, color='k', label='a',norm_hist = True)
sns.distplot(x2, color='g', label='b',norm_hist = True)
sns.distplot(x3, color='b', label='b',norm_hist = True)
sns.distplot(x4, color='r', label='c',norm_hist = True)
sns.distplot(x5, color='y', label='c',norm_hist = True)
```

For my data, I get this plot
[image]

This is good but what I'm really trying is to fit the curve only on positive x values. Negative duration doesn't make physical sense. Is there any option for that?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`sns.distplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) documentation:

> ... It can also fit scipy.stats distributions and plot the estimated PDF over the data.

So you can choose a non-negative distribution that would make sense for your data and use the `fit` argument to pass a [SciPy distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) object that will be fitted to your data.

For example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.distplot(iris.petal_length, color='k', fit=stats.expon, kde=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the gamma and erlang distributions. It doesn't fit the data well. I tried limiting the x with plt.xlim(0,20) and then fit=norm,kde=False. But as I increase the bin size, a proper fit falls through.

Comment: Looking at your data, maybe a log-normal distribution would be a reasonable fit.